Why does my @Pattern @Size annotations don't work with @Valid (In Spring Boot v.3)?
I'm trying to learn Java using Spring Boot v.3 and to manage a FAKE database with it. This afternoon I was trying to implement some "constraints" for the username and password input via @/Pattern and @/Valid annotations.
That's what I did in my User class:
@Column(nullable = false)
  @Size(min = 5, max = 15)
  @Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d).+$", message = "Password must contain at least one uppercase letter and one number")
  private String password;

And what I did in my Controller class:
@PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> registerUser(
        u/Valid @RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest, 
        BindingResult result) {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(service.registerUser(registerRequest, result));
        } ETC ETC
        }
    }

Since my Controller class is actually using a RegisterRequest DTO, to be sure I have also implemented the annotations there, like this:
The thing is that it is still accepting passwords with only two characters and without numbers of capitals. I'm sure it's my fault, cannot be otherwise, but what can I do?
I've thought that maybe I should "break" the RegisterRequest object in different strings when I send them to the service class in order to "validate" them before starting the service process.
And I did it, but I'm not able to make it work. I mean, I was able to "break" the RegisterRequest Object in several strings, I sent them to UserService (that I have modified in order for it to receive three strings and a boolean) and if I try it with Postman the registration process still works, so the code is "good". But the Valid annotation doesn't work, it doesn't check the constraints Size and Pattern.
Solution
I was adding constraints to the user class and, obviously, after the password is encrypted in UserService, what comes back to be inserted in the db is way more than 25 characters (the limit I put), so that's way it was always giving me errors.
On the contrary, I had to add constraints to my RegisterRequest class and valid them in the controller, with @Valid. As simple as that. After the validation, the service takes place and then the data can be checked with the db for duplicates and then finally added to it.

Can you create minimal reproducible example ? Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Hi Alex, thank you for you comment and time. I've read about MRE but honestly I cannot do it now. If have understood well, to create a MRE, tomorrow I create a fake entity with only username as colum and I will do controller and service by consequence. I will first test it (maybe the problem is in the authentication) and then send it here (should I add it to my post or in a comment?). But I'm not sure that's what I should do

Which annotations are you using (include the imports) and what dependencies are you using? You are using Spring Boot so add spring-boot-starter-validation don't add things like validation-api yourself (as you probably included the wrong one).

Ok... I've found the problem. I was adding constraints to the user class and, obviously, after the password is encrypted, it is way more than 25 characters (the limit I put), so that's it was always giving me errors. On the contrary, I had to add constraints to my RegisterRequest class and valid them in the controller. After the validation, the service takes place and then the data can be checked with the db for duplicates and then finally added to it.
I will edit my message for future dumb persons like me.

How to implement input validation in controller
Include dependency
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

In controller mark request body with corresponding annotation
    @PostMapping
    public String post(@Valid @RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
        return "It works, age="+registerRequest.user.age;
    }

If RegisterRequest uses other object that should be validated, mark them with annotation too:
public class RegisterRequest {

    @Valid
    public User user;

}

At that point user will be validated. Put validation constraints to it:
public class User {

    @Min(value = 18, message = "age too low")
    public Integer age;
    
}

That is almost all. The main thing - you should add @Valid annotation in all parts of the request way - in controller, in service and end objects. A little thing remains - we want to show error message in response, as not a "Bad request" but as "age too low". For that ControllerAdvice serves.
Controller advice
Controller advice catches exceptions from all controllers and all methods. So we can write one advice only for the whole application. Here is a simple example
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerAdvice {
    /**
     * Very simple ExceptionHandler returning first error only
     */
    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<String> handle(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
        String errorMessage = exception.getMessage();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}

Now if we post the body
{
    "user": {"age": 10}
}

we shall get in response a long error text ending with age too low

Hei, thank you! I have tried also your method, but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm stupid, but I have lost any hope to solve this problem. I have also an error handler and it says there are no error, that's why he goes on with the registration, because it doesn't see any problem with constraints. He only find problems if I obviously use an already registered email or username

Ok... I've found the problem. I was adding constraints to the user class and, obviously, after the password is encrypted, it is way more than 25 characters (the limit I put), so that's it was always giving me errors. On the contrary, I had to add constraints to my RegisterRequest class and valid them in the controller. After the validation, the service takes place and then the data can be checked with the db for duplicates and then finally added to it.
I will edit my message for future dumb persons like me.

@Litmanen84 Congratulations! You can use my answer as an example for writing MRE next time
